Weird Programming Glitch
Yesterday, when I was programming, my computer suddenly crashed. When I rebooted, I saw the message flicker before me:
HAHAHALMAOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO = ሁ၁ሁ၁ሁ၁ጁፁ၁Ꮪ

Then it flickered off. Then appeared two more messages.
(It is recommended to copy paste them. I have tested this and copy pasting does not lose any data.)
ʁᛁቁᮁᴁᲁᯁᝁʁᄁ᥁᳁᥁ᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁᏁᯁᨁୁᯂᨁୁᯂᨁୁᯂᨁʁሁᵁᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʂᛁᖁ᥁ᲁ᳁᥁ࠁుᝁʁᗁ᥁ুᲁ᥁ࠁᮁᯁࠁ᳁ᴁᲁᡁᮁᧁ᥁ᲁ᳁ࠁᴁᯁࠁᬁᯁᶁ᥁ʁᙁᯁᵁࠁ᫁ᮁᯁ᷁ࠁᴁᨁ᥁ࠁᲁᵁᬁ᥁᳁ࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁ᳁ᯁࠁᤁᯁࠁቁࠁਁᄁᯁࠁቁੁʁ၁ࠁᦁᵁᬂࠁᣁᯁᭂᩁᴁᭁ᥁ᮁᴁু᳁ࠁ᷁ᨁᡁᴁࠁቁুᭁࠁᴁᨁᩁᮁ᫁ᩁᮁᧁࠁᯁᦁʁᙁᯁᵁࠁ᷁ᯁᵁᬁᤁᮁুᴁࠁᧁ᥁ᴁࠁᴁᨁᩁ᳁ࠁᦁᲁᯁᭁࠁᡁᮁṁࠁᯁᴁᨁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᵁṁʂᛁᐁᲁ᥁ୁჁᨁᯁᲁᵁ᳁ᝁʁቁࠁ᪁ᵁ᳁ᴁࠁ᷁ᡁᮂᡁࠁᴁ᥁ᬂࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᨁᯁ᷁ࠁቁুᭁࠁᦁ᥂ᬁᩁᮁᧁʁᇁᯁᴂᡁࠁᭁᡁ᫁᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᮁᤁ᥁ᲁ᳁ᴁᡁᮁᤁʂᛁჁᨁᯁᲁᵁ᳁ᝁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᧁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᰁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᬁ᥁ᴁࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᤁᯁ᷁ᮁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᲁᵁᮁࠁᡁᲁᯁᵁᮁᤁࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᤁ᥁᳁᥁ᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᭁᡁ᫁᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᣁᲁṁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁ᳁ᡁṁࠁᧁᯂᤁᢁṁ᥁ʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᴁ᥁ᬂࠁᡁࠁᬁᩁ᥁ࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᨁᵁᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʂᛁᖁ᥁ᲁ᳁᥁ࠁಁᝁʁᗁ᥁ুᶁ᥁ࠁ᫁ᮁᯁ᷁ᮁࠁ᥁ᡁᣁᨁࠁᯁᴁᨁ᥁ᲁࠁᦁᯁᲁࠁ᳁ᯁࠁᬁᯁᮁᧁʁᙁᯁᵁᲁࠁᨁ᥁ᡁᲁᴁু᳁ࠁᢁ᥂ᮁࠁᡁᣁᨁᩁᮁᧁଁࠁᢁᵁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁুᲁ᥁ࠁᴁᯂࠁ᳁ᨁṁࠁᴁᯁࠁ᳁ᡁṁࠁᩁᴁࠁਁᔁᯁࠁ᳁ᡁṁࠁᩁᴁੁʁቁᮁ᳁ᩁᤁ᥁ଁࠁ᷁᥁ࠁᢁᯁᴁᨁࠁ᫁ᮁᯁ᷁ࠁ᷁ᨁᡁᴁু᳁ࠁᢁ᥂ᮁࠁᧁᯁᩁᮁᧁࠁᯁᮁࠁਁᇁᯁᩁᮁᧁࠁᯁᮁੁʁᗁ᥁ࠁ᫁ᮁᯁ᷁ࠁᴁᨁ᥁ࠁᧁᡁᭁ᥁ଁࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁ᷁᥁ুᲁ᥁ࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᰁᬁᡁṁࠁᩁᴁʂᛁᐁᲁ᥁ୁჁᨁᯁᲁᵁ᳁ᝁʁ၁ᮁᤁࠁᩁᦁࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᡁ᳁᫁ࠁᭁ᥁ࠁᨁᯁ᷁ࠁቁুᭁࠁᦁ᥂ᬁᩁᮁᧁʁᄁᯁᮁুᴁࠁᴁ᥁ᬂࠁᭁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁুᲁ᥁ࠁᴁᯂࠁᢁᬁᩁᮁᤁࠁᴁᯁࠁ᳁᥂ʂᛁჁᨁᯁᲁᵁ᳁ᝁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᧁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᰁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᬁ᥁ᴁࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᤁᯁ᷁ᮁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᲁᵁᮁࠁᡁᲁᯁᵁᮁᤁࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᤁ᥁᳁᥁ᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᭁᡁ᫁᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᣁᲁṁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁ᳁ᡁṁࠁᧁᯂᤁᢁṁ᥁ʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᴁ᥁ᬂࠁᡁࠁᬁᩁ᥁ࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᨁᵁᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᧁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᰁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᬁ᥁ᴁࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᤁᯁ᷁ᮁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᲁᵁᮁࠁᡁᲁᯁᵁᮁᤁࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᤁ᥁᳁᥁ᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᭁᡁ᫁᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᣁᲁṁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁ᳁ᡁṁࠁᧁᯂᤁᢁṁ᥁ʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᴁ᥁ᬂࠁᡁࠁᬁᩁ᥁ࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᨁᵁᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʂᛁᐁᯁ᳁ᴁୁჁᨁᯁᲁᵁ᳁ᝁʁᏁᯁᨁࠁਁᇁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᰁੁʁᏁᯁᨁୁᯂᨁࠁਁᇁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᰁੁʁᏁᯁᨁୁᯂᨁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᧁᩁᶁ᥁ଁࠁᮁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᧁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁਁᇁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᰁੁʁᏁᯁᨁୁᯂᨁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᧁᩁᶁ᥁ଁࠁᮁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᧁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁਁᇁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᰁੁʂᛁႁᲁᩁᤁᧁ᥁ᝁʁᗁ᥁ুᶁ᥁ࠁ᫁ᮁᯁ᷁ᮁࠁ᥁ᡁᣁᨁࠁᯁᴁᨁ᥁ᲁࠁᦁᯁᲁࠁ᳁ᯁࠁᬁᯁᮁᧁʁᙁᯁᵁᲁࠁᨁ᥁ᡁᲁᴁু᳁ࠁᢁ᥂ᮁࠁᡁᣁᨁᩁᮁᧁଁࠁᢁᵁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁুᲁ᥁ࠁᴁᯂࠁ᳁ᨁṁࠁᴁᯁࠁ᳁ᡁṁࠁᩁᴁࠁਁᔁᯁࠁ᳁ᡁṁࠁᩁᴁੁʁቁᮁ᳁ᩁᤁ᥁ଁࠁ᷁᥁ࠁᢁᯁᴁᨁࠁ᫁ᮁᯁ᷁ࠁ᷁ᨁᡁᴁু᳁ࠁᢁ᥂ᮁࠁᧁᯁᩁᮁᧁࠁᯁᮁࠁਁᇁᯁᩁᮁᧁࠁᯁᮁੁʁᗁ᥁ࠁ᫁ᮁᯁ᷁ࠁᴁᨁ᥁ࠁᧁᡁᭁ᥁ଁࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁ᷁᥁ুᲁ᥁ࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᰁᬁᡁṁࠁᩁᴁʂᛁᐁᲁ᥁ୁჁᨁᯁᲁᵁ᳁ᝁʁቁࠁ᪁ᵁ᳁ᴁࠁ᷁ᡁᮂᡁࠁᴁ᥁ᬂࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᨁᯁ᷁ࠁቁুᭁࠁᦁ᥂ᬁᩁᮁᧁʁᇁᯁᴂᡁࠁᭁᡁ᫁᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᮁᤁ᥁ᲁ᳁ᴁᡁᮁᤁʂᛁჁᨁᯁᲁᵁ᳁ᝁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᧁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᰁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᬁ᥁ᴁࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᤁᯁ᷁ᮁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᲁᵁᮁࠁᡁᲁᯁᵁᮁᤁࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᤁ᥁᳁᥁ᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᭁᡁ᫁᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᣁᲁṁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁ᳁ᡁṁࠁᧁᯂᤁᢁṁ᥁ʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᴁ᥁ᬂࠁᡁࠁᬁᩁ᥁ࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᨁᵁᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᧁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᰁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᬁ᥁ᴁࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᤁᯁ᷁ᮁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᲁᵁᮁࠁᡁᲁᯁᵁᮁᤁࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᤁ᥁᳁᥁ᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᭁᡁ᫁᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᣁᲁṁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁ᳁ᡁṁࠁᧁᯂᤁᢁṁ᥁ʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᴁ᥁ᬂࠁᡁࠁᬁᩁ᥁ࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᨁᵁᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᧁᩁᶁ᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᵁᰁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᬁ᥁ᴁࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᤁᯁ᷁ᮁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᲁᵁᮁࠁᡁᲁᯁᵁᮁᤁࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᤁ᥁᳁᥁ᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᭁᡁ᫁᥁ࠁṁᯁᵁࠁᣁᲁṁʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁ᳁ᡁṁࠁᧁᯂᤁᢁṁ᥁ʁᎁ᥁ᶁ᥁ᲁࠁᧁᯁᮂᡁࠁᴁ᥁ᬂࠁᡁࠁᬁᩁ᥁ࠁᡁᮁᤁࠁᨁᵁᲁᴁࠁṁᯁᵁʁ

This next one can be decoded in the same way, but might need a little computer-science to understand:
ᴁࠁཁࠁূʁᦁᯁᲁࠁេࠁᩁᮁࠁ᳁ກࠁᴁࠁુཁࠁਁඁುঁᯁᲁᤁਁេੂઁᣁᨁᲁਁᯁᲁᤁਁេੁྂඁੁʁᰁᲁᩁᮁᴁਁᴁੁ

Can you help me decipher them?

If you know "This next one can be decoded in the same way" then why do you need help deciphering them?

I mean, how could I have memorized the messages? How could I have known that copy-pasting does not lose any data? How do I know that this is a computer-puzzle cipher and need a little computer-science? Obviously it is part of the story. Does Gladys exist? I hope so, but probably not.

Is this Unicode?

rot13(V qba'g xabj vs guvf vf pbeerpg, ohg vs lbh vtaber gur fgevat bs 'B'f ba gur raq bs gur cynvagrkg naq gur F-yvxr punenpgre ng gur raq bs gur pbeerfcbaqvat pvcuregrkg, gura gur erznvavat punenpgref znc bar gb bar, jurer gur qvfgnapr orgjrra gur pbqrcbvag sbe gur pbeerfcbaqvat yrggre vf 64 gvzrf abezny.)

rot13(Frr guvf yvax sbe zber vasbezngvba: uggcf://ngb.ckrtre.pbz/eha?1=cqZ9H4ZjTZQkjL1C8HlznSgrGOUxBaQdUDBZmu6TJYaQEVUJhMhQstXKQidy3CjzWek4TBa1iP4ZhG_j_NW5r2p8cMiAk7X6aovsO3FISOOpKm4hfkKZNK2g18t3wXgwl8GJTSWXfifxu6jRoQzJWhhjIm93gJ0dgJA6qE316crhCySe15aIqqleK39dqEYC9wFApSolaR5miuvuv6lfRxLb3AQdvIVTNEkPrVoTtRV0WKqWpF7LDGHlqMtNPcD13q_kBZXYtcLCaXHMJ4P8AlRIYHe5uaL__ejyTSeKsGPZraqRVoqHHQS2kqKOE6r_cuOQ7MtdSZvbExLQFOJ-SmYntumRg0wkHFIFJhqtm5jTvs-WwNDlecUkNSXS74JZglNU8F1F_VfFXn2F1ktgkqvpgioDqLsiTj)

rot13(Guvf qvqa'g jbex jura V gevrq gb nccyl vg gb gur haxabja grkgf gubhtu.)

I, too, enjoy weird Unicode symbols.


 You've just been rickrolled.


 [Intro]
 Desert you
 Ooh-ooh-ooh-ooh
 Hurt you

 [Verse 1]
 We're no strangers to love
 You know the rules and so do I (Do I)
 A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
 You wouldn't get this from any other guy

 [Pre-Chorus]
 I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
 Gotta make you understand

 [Chorus]
 Never gonna give you up
 Never gonna let you down
 Never gonna run around and desert you
 Never gonna make you cry
 Never gonna say goodbye
 Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you

 [Verse 2]
 We've known each other for so long
 Your heart's been aching, but you're too shy to say it (To say it)
 Inside, we both know what's been going on (Going on)
 We know the game, and we're gonna play it

 [Pre-Chorus]
 And if you ask me how I'm feeling
 Don't tell me you're too blind to see

 [Chorus]
 Never gonna give you up
 Never gonna let you down
 Never gonna run around and desert you
 Never gonna make you cry
 Never gonna say goodbye
 Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you
 Never gonna give you up
 Never gonna let you down
 Never gonna run around and desert you
 Never gonna make you cry
 Never gonna say goodbye
 Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you

 [Post-Chorus]
 Ooh (Give you up)
 Ooh-ooh (Give you up)
 Ooh-ooh
 Never gonna give, never gonna give (Give you up)
 Ooh-ooh
 Never gonna give, never gonna give (Give you up)

 [Bridge]
 We've known each other for so long
 Your heart's been aching, but you're too shy to say it (To say it)
 Inside, we both know what's been going on (Going on)
 We know the game, and we're gonna play it

 [Pre-Chorus]
 I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
 Gotta make you understand

 [Chorus]
 Never gonna give you up
 Never gonna let you down
 Never gonna run around and desert you
 Never gonna make you cry
 Never gonna say goodbye
 Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you
 Never gonna give you up
 Never gonna let you down
 Never gonna run around and desert you
 Never gonna make you cry
 Never gonna say goodbye
 Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you
 Never gonna give you up
 Never gonna let you down
 Never gonna run around and desert you
 Never gonna make you cry
 Never gonna say goodbye
 Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you

Decoding the second message gives:

 
 t = ''
 for _ in s: t += (63&ord())*chr(ord()>> 6)
 print(t)
 

Which just so happens to be the python code to decode these messages!
Explanation
I noticed that when I assumed that ሁ was equivalent to H, and so on using the first encoded message given (၁ = A, ጁ = L, etc), the difference in the unicode code points of the encrypted letters was exactly 64 times the difference in the code points of the unencrypted letters. The only thing that threw me off was the Ꮪ. I knew it had to be equivalent to the 26 Os in the plaintext, but wasn't sure how it decoded. More on that later.
Making the conversion tables
Going off of this information, I wrote a program to convert each of the 128 ASCII characters (or first 128 Unicode characters) into their corresponding encrypted character. This gave me this table:



ascii letter
encrypted letter




0
ఁ


1
ు


2
ಁ


3
ು


4
ഁ


5
ു


6
ඁ


7
ශ


8
ก


9
แ


(tab)
Ɂ


(newline)
ʁ


(space)
ࠁ


!
ࡁ


"
ࢁ


#
ࣁ


$
ँ


%
ु


&
ঁ


'
ু


(
ਁ


)
ੁ


*
ઁ


+
ુ


,
ଁ


-
ୁ


.
஁


/
ு


:
ກ


;
ແ


<
༁


=
ཁ


>
ཱྀ


?
࿁


@
ခ


A
၁


B
ႁ


C
Ⴡ


D
ᄁ


E
ᅁ


F
ᆁ


G
ᇁ


H
ሁ


I
ቁ


J
ኁ


K
዁


L
ጁ


M
ፁ


N
ᎁ


O
Ꮑ


P
ᐁ


Q
ᑁ


R
ᒁ


S
ᓁ


T
ᔁ


U
ᕁ


V
ᖁ


W
ᗁ


X
ᘁ


Y
ᙁ


Z
ᚁ


[
ᛁ


\
ᜁ


]
ᝁ


^
ខ


_
េ


`
᠁


a
ᡁ


b
ᢁ


c
ᣁ


d
ᤁ


e
᥁


f
ᦁ


g
ᧁ


h
ᨁ


i
ᩁ


j
᪁


k
᫁


l
ᬁ


m
ᭁ


n
ᮁ


o
ᯁ


p
ᰁ


q
᱁


r
ᲁ


s
᳁


t
ᴁ


u
ᵁ


v
ᶁ


w
᷁


x
ḁ


y
ṁ


z
ẁ


{
ề


|
ἁ


}
ὁ


~
ᾁ



Decoding the Messages (and The Mystery of the Repeated Letters)
I used the program to try and decode the messages, and it mostly worked. However, there were some characters that didn't decode. When I looked at it, they all were in place of a repeated letter. With that, I looked at the code point itself. Here's how they work:
Ꮪ: U+ABAA (5082 in decimal)
encrypted 'O': Ꮑ (5057 in decimal)
So, in the example, there are 26 'O's (1 + 25 repeated).
Therefore, to consolidate repeated letters, you add the number of repeated letters to the code point, giving you the new character.

Knowing how to decode the repeated letters, I was able to manually decode the repeated letters, giving the final message.
If you want to see my code, go here

iIntended! this is a type of run length encoding
